# Keep reading text file from another function

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a program that reads a text file and according to the first character in the line, does a certain type of operation.

In one case, I need to be able to read and apply an undefined amount of words on a line. So what I tried to do was send the stream as a parameter, but that doesn't work.

Can I read a text file opened from another function from the current line to another function? I would normally have not used another function, but since I need to create a new node from a class I believe that's what I should do. Sorry if I'm not clear in my explanation, my mother tongue is not english.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "listeCommandes.h"
#include "listeClients.h"
...
int main(){
listeClients listeClients;
    listeCommande listeCommande;
    std::ifstream operationsAExecuter;
switch(CharOp)
case '=': 
listeCommande.newOrder(operationsAExecuter);
                break;

int listeCommande::newOrder(std::istream fichierTransaction)
{
   // Apply code where I create new node here from undetermined number of words in the line.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can't make a copy of a file stream?  Perhaps try passing a const reference to the stream into the function.

Comment: You can't copy the stream but you can pass a reference.

Comment: How would I do that? I get the error E0415

Comment: References will be covered early on in any non-fraudulent C++ programming text.

Comment: Change `int listeCommande::newOrder(std::istream fichierTransaction)` to `int listeCommande::newOrder(std::istream & fichierTransaction)`  and make no other changes.